# user ajax to get data without "onClick function" in javaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've been searching for the example of getting data by using ajax without onclick function but most of the example that i found was within onclick funtion.
Here is the html that i successfully get the data by using Onclick funtion

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>New document</title>

   <script type = 'text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.2.0.js'></script>

<script type ='text/javascript' src='js/testScript.js'></script>

<?php
include_once("database_conn_getOffers.php");
?>
</head>
<body>
   content goes here
   <aside id="offer" onclick ="loadDoc('getData.php',myFunction)">
        &nbsp; click here
        </aside>
</body>
```

here is the script

```
function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xhttp) {
  document.getElementById("offer").innerHTML =
  xhttp.responseText;
}
```

Now, i wanted get the data without the onclick function. 
I want the data show once i open the html.
Can someone provide me some link or gv me an example ??

Comment: Why don't you move the function call out of onclick and within <script> tags? That should resolve it.

Comment: you have the `loadDoc` function which is independed to `onClick`, you may call it from wherever you want. Perhaps you want to ask how to call a function when the page loads?

Comment: Thanks for every suggestion and answer! i've learnt a new things today! =) Much Appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body onload doesnt required. You can directly use window onload function in JS

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
  loadDoc('getData.php',myFunction)
};
```

Comment: He needs to remove the `onclick` event over which the function is loading if im not wrong.

Comment: That was the question.. :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is call the function elsewhere for instance you could set it to be called when the window is loaded.

`Window.onload = loadDoc('getData.php',myFunction)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`<body onload="loadDoc('getData.php',myFunction);">`

Answer (score 1):

A third solution could be to add a new `DOMContentLoaded` event to send the query after the browser render the page.

It should be something like this :

`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadDoc);`

Answer (score 1):

You have bound ajax call to an event `onclick` where what you want is at page load.
So replace the onclick to **`onload`**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>New document</title>

   <script type = 'text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.2.0.js'></script>

   <script type ='text/javascript' src='js/testScript.js'></script>

<?php
include_once("database_conn_getOffers.php");
?>
</head>
<body>
  content goes here
   <aside id="offer" onload ="loadDoc('getData.php',myFunction)">
    &nbsp; click here
   </aside>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

below code will ideally work if the page of same domain.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>New document</title>

   <script type = 'text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.2.0.js'></script>

<script type ='text/javascript' src='js/testScript.js'></script>
<script type ='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#offer" ).load( 'getData.php' );
});
</script>

<?php
include_once("database_conn_getOffers.php");
?>
</head>
<body>
   content goes here
   <aside id="offer" >
        &nbsp; click here
        </aside>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Call your function in `window.onload` event instead of `onclick`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>New document</title>

   <script type = 'text/javascript' src='js/jquery-2.2.0.js'></script>

<script type ='text/javascript' src='js/testScript.js'></script>

<?php
include_once("database_conn_getOffers.php");
?>
</head>
<body>
   content goes here
   <aside id="offer">
        Your function has been executed onload of document
        </aside>
</body>
```

here is the script

```
window.onload = function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xhttp) {
  document.getElementById("offer").innerHTML =
  xhttp.responseText;

};
```